# Why multiple option in vunion function of the vecsets package does not work for character vectors?

Tags: r

When I run the code:

```
library(vecsets)
p <- c("a","b")
q <- c( "a")
vunion(p,q, multiple = TRUE)
```

I get the result:

```
[1] "a" "b"
```

But I expect the result to be

```
vunion(p,q, multiple = TRUE)
[1] "a" "b" "a"
```

I also do not understand the result provided in the example of the vesect package. The example shows:

```
x <- c(1:5,3,3,3,2,NA,NA)
y <- c(2:5,4,3,NA)

vunion(x,y,multiple=TRUE) 
[1]  2  3  3  4  5 NA  1  3  3  2 NA  4
```

But if we check

```
length(x)+length(y); length(vunion(x,y))
[1] 18
[1] 12
```

we get different lengths, but I think they should be the same. Note, for example, 5 appears only once.

What's going on here?  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `vecset` package documentation ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vecsets/vecsets.pdf)) describes this behavior quite well:

> The `base::union` function removes duplicates per algebraic set theory. `vunion` does not, and so returns as many duplicate elements as are in **either** input vector (**not the sum** of their inputs.) In short, `vunion` is the same as `vintersect(x,y) + vsetdiff(x,y) + vsetdiff(y,x)`.

It's true that you have to read carefully, though.  I've emphasized the important part.  The issue is not with character versus numeric vectors, but rather whether elements are repeated within the same vector or not.  Consider p1 versus p2 in the following example.  The result from `vunion` will have as many a's as *either* `p` or `q`, so we expect 1 "a" in the first part and two a's in the second part; both times we expect only 1 "b":

```
library(vecsets)
q <- c("a", "b")

p1 <- c("a", "b")
vunion(p1, q, multiple = TRUE)
[1] "a" "b" 

p2 <- c("a", "a", "b")
vunion(p2, q, multiple = TRUE)
[1] "a" "b" "a"
```